# What is the meaning of "date for a date"?

Tags: british-english

I was in a meeting in Ireland where we were choosing deadline for tasks.

In the meeting note there was the following statement:

- Task should be done by January 2015 (i.e. "date for a date" )

What is the meaning of "date for a date" ?

Comment: One can only guess, since you have X'd out the actual task: perhaps the date on which some other date must be known? As in, by January 1st we will need to have a clear sense of the delivery date for the final deliverable.

Comment: I'm removing the XX'd as misleading

Comment: Any connection to this? http://www.dateforadate.com/DateForADate.aspx

Comment: Other than that, my googlefu is returning a bunch of database query/sql-type results... I have no idea...

Comment: @miltonaut no, tasks are totally unrelated to these dating service.

Comment: It may mean that in January the team will give an estimate of when the work can be completed. We often set a deadline for when we will finish our assessment of the task and provide the date we can realistically complete it.

Comment: This usually means the time by which some other date should or must be decided upon. So in this case: The task of deciding when to do X (or when it will occur) must be decided by Jan 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **date for a date** is a common term in technology companies for the date by which you expect to have determined another date.  It sounds as though in your meeting you were determining many deadlines for many tasks, and that this determination was itself challenging or time-consuming, and so a deadline had been set *for the task of determining the other deadlines*.  In other words, your group expected to finish assigning all the deadlines by January 2015, even though presumably some of those deadlines would themselves be later dates.